# Rascal: What is the difference between "label" and "name" in the Syntax Definition documentation?

Tags: rascal

The [SyntaxDefinition documentation page](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/SyntaxDefinition.html) of Rascal has two sections, where one speaks about "labels" (starting with *"Each alternative of a syntax definition is defined by a list of Symbols."*), the other about "names" (starting with *"Alternatives can be named or not."*). For both items a list of effects are given that largely overlap, e.g. both enable the `is` operator, are necessary for imploding ParseTrees or for writing Action functions. The Syntax section at the top of the page only lists a `Name` component, and `Tags` but no labels.

Is "label" an alternative term for "name"? And if so why do the lists of the effects using them differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation page could use some love indeed.

The "labels" that are talked about function as *optionally* declared "names" for two different kinds of things:

1. alternative rules of a non-terminal may have a label, as in `syntax E = add: E "+" E | sub: E "-" E;`
2. symbol positions inside a syntax rule may have a label, as in `syntax E = E lhs "+" E rhs | E lhs "-" E rhs;`

Having a label on a rule enables different functionality from having a label on a symbol position.

For rules we get:

- `myExp is myLabel` ; checks to see if the top parse tree node has a syntax rule labeled with that label
- `ParseTree::implode` uses the rule labels to map concrete parse tree nodes to abstract data tree nodes
- When writing a post-parse disambiguation filter, an Action filter, you must use the alternative name to bind the filter to the proper parsetree node, as in `Exp add(Exp lhs, Exp rhs) { ... }` will be called when constructing `syntax Exp = add: Exp "+" Exp;`

For symbol positions we get:

- `myExp has myLabel`; checks to see whether the current parse tree node has a syntax rule where one of the symbol positions is labeled with `myLabel`
- `myExp.myLabel`; projects out the tree at the labeled position from given parse tree
- `myExp.myLabel = newExp`; replaces the tree at the labeled position in the given parse tree

Comment: Greate, I think I get it. I guess the symbol position labels are newer and haven't made it into the the Syntax section of the SyntaxDefinition page yet. About terminology, when you write _"...whether the current parse tree node has a syntax rule..."_ you mean that the tree node has children corresponding to that rule, right?!

Comment: Well yes, but also the entire syntax rule is represented in every parse tree node. See the definition of the `appl` constructor of the Tree datatype in the ParseTree module.

Comment: Wow, so every parse tree node carries the rule that created it, together with the list of its children. And when traversing the parse tree you can actually inspect the rule at each node.

Comment: Yes! And some metadata associated with each rule, like additional “tags”, associativity. This info is used by generic IDE features, like code folding and outlines. The exact same rule representation can be obtained by “reifying” a non-terminal with the `#Type` expression; example: `#Exp.definitions` returns the whole grammar for Exp in “prod” notation.

Comment: But mostly this representation is ideal for concrete syntax matching. No magic, just parse trees.